# Inherit Bootstrap button text color from surrounding div with gradient color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, linear-gradients

I'm designing a web page using MVC, ASP.NET and Twitter Bootstrap. I'd like to create a button that inherits its text font color from the surrounding div's background color. When I set the buttons CSS style like `color: transparent` the text is not readable because it is the same color as the button.

Is there a way to do this in CSS or do I have to use JS or jQuery to achieve this?

Here is an example:

```css
.red {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 33%, #FFFFFF 66%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, red 33%, #FFFFFF 66%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red 33%, #FFFFFF 66%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(left, red 33%, #FFFFFF 66%); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

.custom {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
<button class="btn custom" type="input">
Button
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this jQuery code:

```
var divColor = $(".red").css("backgroundColor");

$(".custom").css("color", divColor);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I need the text font in the surrounding `div` gradient color and not a static color. The `background-color: red` was just a fall back for browsers which don't support gradient.